# How to identify in code that webpart is used full-width in SPFx

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx

Currently i'm able to create webpart in SharePoint that is allowed to use in full-width mode(manifest:"supportsFullBleed": true). But i need to change some styles accordingly. Is there any way how to identify that webpart is used full-width in code?
SPFx used: 1.15.2

I tried check of width of element, it works in some cases, but when full-width webpart is used in for example mobile than width its not reliable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not a supported method, I have found that full-width sections have a css class of CanvasZone--fullWidth, while normal sections do not.

[image]

This means that within your web part, you can query the dom tree for a parent with this class. If it finds one, then your web part is in a full-width section.

For example, in webpart.onInit:

```
const fullWidth = this.domElement.closest(".CanvasZone--fullWidth") !== null;
```

Similar technique can be used to detect if the web part is in a vertical section

```
const isVertical = this.domElement.closest(".CanvasVerticalSection") !== null;
```

Answer (score 1):

The best shot I've seen regarding this may be the "formFactor" context property (it's hidden/not available with type definitions, but actually it exists):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/sp-webpart-base/basewebpartcontext?view=sp-typescript-latest#@microsoft-sp-webpart-base-basewebpartcontext-formfactor-member

Comment: this.context.formFactor seems to apply to webparts that are on pages with layout SingleWebPartAppPage (value=1, otherwise 0). Possibly webparts that are hosted as Teams Apps/Tabs too, but I didn't test that.